# Translation of “name-dropping”

Tags: traduction, anglais

What is the translation of “name-dropping” in French?

I found "lâcher de noms" but it sounds a bit strange to my ears. Are there any more fluent alternatives?

---

name-dropping [=](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/235154?redirectedFrom=name-dropping) The practice of casually mentioning the names of well-known or eminent people as if one knows them, in order to impress others.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example ? Context ? What does it mean in english ?

Comment: @ Random: des exemples en français http://lerapenfrance.fr/rap-name-dropping-1/. Je ne connais pas de « mot unique », on dit parfois « faire son intéressant  ».

Comment: @Random added to the question

Comment: In English, name-droppers usually prefer to describe their words as “paying homage to [the named celebrity],” but just as in English, I imagine that unless said/written with obvious sarcasm or scare quotes, “rendre/en rendant hommage à” would not mean “name-drop/ping.”

Answer (score 3):

Officiellement, rien n'est clair et on a le choix entre anglicisme et longue périphrase :

- [Le collins utilise l'anglicisme tel quel](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/name-dropping), [Le Wiktionnary également](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/name-dropping) "**Faire du name dropping**".
- [Le Figaro désapprouve l’utilisation de l'anglicisme](http://www.lefigaro.fr/culture/2016/03/15/03004-20160315ARTFIG00022-ces-dix-anglicismes-qu-il-faudrait-eradiquer-du-francais.php) et propose "**se faire remarquer de ses interlocuteurs en citant nonchalamment un nom connu de tous**"
- [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/name-dropping) parle de "**balancer des noms connus**". On peut remplacer "balancer" par un verbe moins vulgaire tel que "placer"...
- [Reverso utilise une périphrase](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/name-dropping) (**émailler sa conversation de nom connus**, ou **faire allusion ostensible à des célébrités**)
- Le [larousse utilise également une périphrase](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/name-dropping/596856) : "**allusion fréquente à des personnes connues dans le but d'impressionner**"
- Les québécquois du [grand dictionnaire](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8410686) disent simplement "**snob**"

Personellement, je dirais du **placement de nom** (de la même manière que les anglais utilisent *product placement* pour les films qui camouflent des marques de manière grossièrement subliminal).

J'aurai tendance à penser que si on veut laisser une chance à un mot, il faut qu'il soit court et compréhensible. Les anglais utilisent "**brand-name dropping**" pour un prétentieux qui signale des marques de luxe qu'il possède dans une conversation. Ce qui m'incite à penser que le pont entre *marque* et *nom* peut être fait.

Comment: Thanks, le figaro definitely doesn't help on that one :)

Comment: le "placement de produit" est une démarche où la marque rémunère les producteurs du film pour que la marque apparaisse dans le film. C'est donc de la pub pour la marque. Ici, je ne pense pas que ce soit la même idée. Le but est de donner une image au chanteur (ou autre) grâce aux marques, ce qui est le phénomène inverse...

Comment: Le placement de noms (appelé comme le dit @Random aussi placement de produit) n'a rien à voir avec le *name-dropping*, c'est un acte qui fait l'objet d'une transaction commerciale.

Comment: L'idée est ici de donner une meilleur image à la personne qui parle grâce au nom de célébrité, il est vrai que c'est l'inverse qui a lieu dans le product placement. Peut être que de parler du placement de produit induit en erreur alors que "placement de nom" serait compréhensible sinon..

Comment: Merci j'ai édité le commentaire pour ajouter ces deux références. Celle du grand dictionnaire est particulièrement intéressante.

Answer (score 1):

Il faut peut-être trouver une adaptation élégante suivant le contexte, par exemple **une conversation truffée de noms célèbres**.  Sur [ce blog](http://fattorius.over-blog.com/article-31145710.html) est proposé  **parachutage onomastique**, un peu long, mais joli. Le placer dans la conversation d'un air entendu peut produire son effet, comme dire *[parangonage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parangonnage#fr)* pour *benchmark*.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt sorry for the answer in French. Indeed, "parachutage" has a depreciative meaning in some contexts

Answer (score 1):

Sur *Termium* un traducteur a proposé « [nominite](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=NAME-DROPPING&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) ». Ça ne vient pas avec une explication mais on trouve le mot « nom » ou une partie du verbe « nommer » et le suffixe [*-ite*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ite) est utilisé en médecine pour des affections (ce qui autoriserait des tournures avec « faire de la », « souffrir de », « être atteint de/d'une ») et par analogie plaisante avec des substantifs féminins afin de créer un terme « désignant un goût immodéré pour quelque chose, une admiration excessive pour quelqu'un, une manie » (TLFi). Bien vu !

Answer (score 1):

Une autre statégie dans certains contextes c'est de simplement référer aux « grands [noms](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9N0540) » :

> *Give me a break with your name-dropping.* / Arrête avec tes **grands noms**.

Même sans verbe : « les/des grands noms ! ». Dans ces cas-là, le « dropping » est implicite ; dans d'autres cas ça nécessitera « (de) constamment mentionner » ou d'autres formulations identifiées ailleurs. Je trouve ça meilleur que d'employer *faire* avec l'emprunt intégral qui contient un gérondif.